# Property added to a JS object as a prototype is hoisted, whereas a prototype function is not

Tags: javascript, variables, prototype, hoisting

I am (or at least I thought I was) pretty much familiar with the concept of [Hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting) in JavaScript.

Consider the following statements:

> A **function declaration** will be hoisted along with its body, whereas a **function expression** will not; **only the var statement will be hoisted**.
>
> “**Function declarations** and **function variables** are always moved (‘hoisted’) to the top of their JavaScript scope by the JavaScript interpreter” - Berry Cherry

Now consider the following function:

```
function User() {
    this.name = "";
    this.life = 100;
    this.heal = function heal(player) {
        player.life+=5;
        console.log("\nHey" + player.name + "! Player " + this.name + " healed you for 5.");
    } 
}
```

... and the following users:

```
var Dan = new User("Danny");
var Liz = new User("Lizzy");
```

Say I want to add a new ***skill*** in the form of a prototype function to already defined users, like so (appended to the code):

```
User.prototype.uppercut = function uppercut(player) {
    player.life-=10;
    console.log("\nBaaam! " + player.name + ", player " + this.name + " uppercuted you for 10 damage.");
};
```

... and now, use said ***skill*** ***(add this before prototype)***:

```
Liz.uppercut(Dan);
Liz.uppercut(Dan);
```

... I will receive the following error:

```
Liz.uppercut(Dan);
    ^
TypeError: Liz.uppercut is not a function
```

Should I add a property to the User objects using a prototype, but accessing it in the code before the prototype declaration, it will ***work*** (it is hoisted):

```
console.log("Hey there " + Dan.name + "! You have " + Dan.mana + " remaining mana.");
User.prototype.mana = 100;
```

Basically this confirmed to me that the same ***hoisting*** principles which apply to functions & variables, also apply to prototypes.

**Question no.1:** Is this logic valid and if so, can you explain why?

**Question no.2:** If there a way to avoid this w/o moving the prototype expression above the prototype function call?

**Thanks** and have a good one!

**Code snippet:**

```js
function User(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.life = 100;
    this.heal = function heal(player) {
        player.life+=5;
        console.log("Hey" + player.name + "! Player " + this.name + " healed you for 5.");
    }
}

var Dan = new User("Danny");
var Liz = new User("Lizzy");

Liz.uppercut(Dan);
Liz.uppercut(Dan);

console.log(Liz.name + " you know have " + Liz.life + " life.");

User.prototype.mana = 100;
User.prototype.uppercut = function (player) {
    player.life-=10;
    console.log("Baaam " + player.name + "! Player " + this.name + " uppercuted you for 10 damage.");
};

console.log("Hey there " + Dan.name + "! You have " + Dan.mana + " remaining mana.");
Dan.mana = 200;
console.log("Hey there " + Dan.name + "! You have " + Dan.mana + " remaining mana.");
```

Comment: Your code works just fine (make a snippet and you'll see). The error is somewhere else. Also, 'hoisting' only applies to variables, object properties are not hoisted in any way.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @georg! Indeed I forgot to mention that I was calling the **uppercut** method before the prototype implementation. I edited the post.  
Also, when you are saying that _object properties are not hoisted in any way_, what are you referring to exactly?  
I added the **mana** snippet (forgot previously) to prove that the object property added via prototype is indeed hoisted, whereas the function expression is not.

Comment: Could you convert your examples to a runnable snippet? (Use the snippet button in the editor). Your question as it stands it pretty hard to follow.

Comment: Doesn’t the `console.log` say “You have undefined remaining mana?”

Comment: @Thai of course it says _undefined_. But that proves that the object property has indeed been **hoisted**.  
You can afterwards go and change the value for each User instance.

Comment: @georg added the snippet at the bottom. So basically my question is: Are prototype functions subject to the same **hoisting** rules as regular function expressions and why?

Comment: @iamdanchiv Hoisting happens for variable declarations and nothing else.

Comment: @iamdanchiv The same thing applies for prototype functions. `Liz.uppercut` gives you `undefined`, which you then call, yielding the “undefined is not a function” error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing **variables** and **properties** here. Variables are hoisted, properties are not.

In your example, `Dan` is a variable, `mana` is a property of `Dan`.

JavaScript handles `undefined` variables differently from `undefined` properties.

Variables are *hoisted* when they are declared, by splitting off the left hand side of the declaration.  i.e. `var Dan = new User("Danny");` is split into two statements, `var Dan;  Dan = new User("Danny");`.  the `var Dan` is then **hoisted** to the top of the function. but the assignment stays in place.

If your code contatined only `Dan = new User("Danny");`, you would receive a ReferenceError, because you would be trying to make an assignment to a variable that isn't declared.  The declaration is missing, thus the variable was never hoisted.

Properties, on the other hand, operate differently.  Property accessors return the result of a hash lookup on the parent object.  In the case of `Dan.mana`, the parent object is defined, so no ReferenceError, but `mana` is not a property of `Dan`, so the hash lookup returns `undefined`.  No hoisting has occurred, because there is no variable declaration.

Therefore, prototypes cannot be tied to hoisting, because they are strictly assignment operations.  Even if the prototype is modified at the beginning of the function, it wouldn't be affected by hoisting, since hoisting ***only*** affects the declaration of the variable, not the assignment (which happens on the right side of the call).

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks a lot @Claies for the detailed answer!

Answer (score 0):

No, assignments (to prototype properties or other) are not hoisted.

The code

> ```
> function User() { this.name = ""; … }
> var Dan = new User("Danny");
> console.log("Hey there " + Dan.name + "! You have " + Dan.mana + " remaining mana.");
> User.prototype.mana = 100;
> ```

does not work, it will log `Hey there ! You have undefined remaining mana.`.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing a property that is not defined on the object will give you `undefined`. There is no hoisting rule in play here.

- `Liz.mana` will give you `undefined`.
- `Liz.uppercut` will also give you `undefined`.
- `Liz.agility` will also give you `undefined`.

Calling `Liz.uppercut(Dan)` throws the error because you are trying to call `Liz.uppercut`, which is `undefined`, as a function. That leads to the “undefined is not a function” error.